# Matching leagues and matches from different tables(arrays)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5

I'm quite new with **Laravel**.

I have a db which contains these tables:

```
 - tournaments(leagues)  
 - matches(with tournament_id)
 - bets(with match_id)
```

I need to match `tournaments` and `matches` like this (tournament, matches of that tournament and placed bets count for that match):

[image]

I do it by taking `tournaments` and and `matches` into two different arrays and printing out them with a foreach nest.

But The problem is when we have too many matches, page load time goes up to 15 sec.

Here is my controller(I know it's not the best code you have ever seen)

```
$tournaments = \DB::table('matches as m') 
  ->select([    
                'm.tournament_id as tournament_id',
                'm.status_desc as status_desc',
                't.results_name as tournament_name',
                'c.name as country',
                'c.code as country_code',
                't.is_popular as popular',
                 \DB::raw('count(b.id) as count'),

            ])
  ->whereRaw('DATE(m.date_hour) = DATE(NOW())')
  ->where('m.status_type', '=','notstarted')
  ->join('tournaments as t','m.tournament_id','=','t.id')
 // ->leftJoin('bets as b','m.id','=','b.match_id')
  ->groupBy('t.id')
  ->join('countries as c','t.country_id','=','c.id')
  ->leftJoin('bets as b','m.id','=','b.match_id')
  ->orderBy('t.is_popular', 'desc')
  ->orderBy(\DB::raw('count(b.id)'), 'desc')
  ->orderBy('c.name', 'asc')
  ->get(); 




  $matches = \DB::table('matches as m') 
  ->select([    'm.id as match_id',
                'm.date_hour as date',
                'm.tournament_id as tournament_id',
                'm.host_id as host_id',
                'm.guest_id as guest_id',
                'm.status_desc as status_desc',
                't.results_name as tournament_name',
                'c.name as country',
                'host.name as host_name',
                'guest.name as guest_name',
            \DB::raw('count(b.id) as count'),

            ])
  ->whereRaw('DATE(m.date_hour) = DATE(NOW())')
  ->where('m.status_type', '=','notstarted')
  ->join('tournaments as t','m.tournament_id','=','t.id')
  ->join('countries as c','t.country_id','=','c.id')
  ->join('teams as host','host.id','=','m.host_id')
  ->join('teams as guest','guest.id','=','m.guest_id')
  ->leftJoin('bets as b','m.id','=','b.match_id')
  ->groupBy('m.id')
  ->get();
```

And here is my view:

```
    @foreach($tournaments as $tournament)

<thead>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion-{{$tournament->tournament_id}}" class="clickable">
            <th style="background-color: #b8312f; color:#fff;text-align:center; " colspan="4">
                <div class="pull-left"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{strtolower($tournament->country_code)}}"></span></div>{{ $tournament->country.' - '.$tournament->tournament_name}}
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" title="Align Justify"></i>
  </a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

@if($tournament->popular == 1 || $tournament->count > 0 )
<tbody id="accordion-{{$tournament->tournament_id}}" class="collapse in" area-expanded="true" >
@else
<tbody id="accordion-{{$tournament->tournament_id}}" class="collapse">
@endif  
@foreach($matches as $match)



        @if($match->tournament_id == $tournament->tournament_id &&  $match->count > 0 )
           <tr class="clickable_row" data-url="{{ URL::route('matches.view',[$match->match_id,str_slug($match->host_name.' vs '.$match->guest_name)])}}" style="cursor: pointer">
            <td><div class="pull-right"> {{$match->host_name}}</div></td>  
            <td style="width:50px!important; background-color:#CCD1D1">{!!(new \Carbon\Carbon($match->date))->format('H:i')!!}</td> 
            <td><div class="pull-left">   {{$match->guest_name}} </div></td> 
             <td style="width:20px!important"><span class="label @if($match->count > 0) label-success @else label-warning @endif">{{$match->count}} @if($match->count == 0 || $match->count == 1) Prediction @else Predictions @endif </span>
            </td>
            </div> </tr>

            @endif


@endforeach
        </tbody>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Relationship in your Model.

Define `hasMany()` relationship like in your model class.

Just try this..

`Tournament.php`

```
class Tournament extends Model
{
    .........
    .........

    public function matches(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Match', 'tournament_id', 'tournament_id');
    }
}
```

`Match.php`

```
class Match extends Model
{
    .........
    .........
    public function bets(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bet', 'match_id', 'match_id');
    }
}
```

`Bet.php`

```
class Bet extends Model
{
    .........
    .........
}
```

Pass data from your controller like,

```
$tournaments = Tournament::all();
```

in your view just perform the `foreach` like,

```
@foreach($tournaments as $tournament)
    //diaplay your tournament UI

    @foreach($tournament->matches as $match)
        //diaplay your match UI
        //display count by `count($match->bets)`
    @enforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer but how I'm going to filter the results? I need to do a lot of filtering and with relations, it seems hard to do so. Also I tried your suggestion and this one turns empty for some reason: $tournament->matches